# How to adjust the width of a system of equations to paragraph length when using systeme

Tags: latex

I am trying to fit a system of equations to the paragraph width. The case is a bit more convoluted than usual because the equations are very large and form a system.

The partial solution that I found was to use "scritpsize" to reduce the size of the equations, but I do not like it much, because it reduces more than needed.

[Document class can be found here](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/jasss-article-template/pnrdvncxsjmn)

I share the code I use below.

```
\documentclass{JASSS}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath,systeme}
\usepackage{tabularx,colortbl}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{p{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\systeme{
\frac{dA_1}{dt}= \mu_1 N_1 - k_{B} p_{B} A_1 \frac{B}{N_1} - (1-k_{B} p_{B}) k_{D} p_{D} A_1 \frac{D}{N_2} - k_{C} p_{C} A_1 \frac{C}{N_1} - (1-k_{C} p_{C}) k_{E} p_{E} A_1 \frac{E}{N_2} - \mu_{A_1} A_1 + \gamma_{B} B + \gamma_{C} C ,  
\frac{dB}{dt}= k_{B} p_{B} A_1 \frac{B}{N_1} + (1-k_{B} p_{B}) k_{D} p_{D} A_1 \frac{D}{N_2} - \phi_{C} B \frac{C}{N_1} - (1-\phi_{C}) \phi_{E} B \frac{E}{N_2} + \phi_{B} C \frac{B}{N_1} + (1-\phi_{B}) \phi_{D} C \frac{D}{N_2} - \mu_{B} B - \gamma_{B} B ,
\frac{dC}{dt}= k_{C} p_{C} A_1 \frac{C}{N_1} + (1-k_{C} p_{C}) k_{E} p_{E} A_1 \frac{E}{N_2} - \phi_{B} C \frac{B}{N_1} - (1-\phi_{B}) \phi_{D} C \frac{D}{N_2} + \phi_{C} B \frac{C}{N_1} + (1-\phi_{C}) \phi_{E} B \frac{E}{N_2} - \mu_{C} C - \gamma_{C} C ,
\frac{dA_2}{dt}=\mu_2 N_2 - k_{D} p_{D} A_2 \frac{D}{N_2} - (1-k_{D} p_{D}) k_{B} p_{B} A_2 \frac{B}{N_1} - k_{E} p_{E} A_2 \frac{E}{N_2} - (1-k_{E} p_{E}) k_{C} p_{C} A_2 \frac{C}{N_1} - \mu_{A_2} A_2 + \gamma_{D} D + \gamma_{E} E ,
\frac{dD}{dt}= k_{D} p_{D} A_2 \frac{D}{N_2} + (1-k_{D} p_{D}) k_{B} p_{B} A_2 \frac{B}{N_1} - \phi_{E} D \frac{E}{N_2} - (1-\phi_{E}) \phi_{C} D \frac{C}{N_1} + \phi_{D} E \frac{D}{N_2} + (1-\phi_{D}) \phi_{B} E \frac{B}{N_1} - \mu_{D} D - \gamma_{D} D ,
\frac{dE}{dt}= k_{E} p_{E} A_2 \frac{E}{N_2} + (1-k_{E} p_{E}) k_{C} p_{C} A_2 \frac{C}{N_1} - \phi_{D} E \frac{D}{N_2} - (1-\phi_{D}) \phi_{B} E \frac{B}{N_1} + \phi_{E} D \frac{E}{N_2} + (1-\phi_{E}) \phi_{C} D \frac{C}{N_1} - \mu_{E} E - \gamma_{E} E }
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as if you are not actually aligning the different terms of your equations, so I don't think using `\system` makes sense. Instead you could use the `cases` environment to add a big curly bracket:

```
\documentclass{JASSS}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
\frac{dA_1}{dt}= &\mu_1 N_1 - k_{B} p_{B} A_1 \frac{B}{N_1} - (1-k_{B} p_{B}) k_{D} p_{D} A_1 \frac{D}{N_2} - k_{C} p_{C} A_1 \frac{C}{N_1} - (1-k_{C} p_{C}) k_{E} p_{E} A_1 \\
&\frac{E}{N_2} - \mu_{A_1} A_1 + \gamma_{B} B + \gamma_{C} C \\
%
\frac{dB}{dt}= &k_{B} p_{B} A_1 \frac{B}{N_1} + (1-k_{B} p_{B}) k_{D} p_{D} A_1 \frac{D}{N_2} - \phi_{C} B \frac{C}{N_1} - (1-\phi_{C}) \phi_{E} B \frac{E}{N_2} + \phi_{B} C \frac{B}{N_1} +\\
& (1-\phi_{B}) \phi_{D} C \frac{D}{N_2} - \mu_{B} B - \gamma_{B} B \\
%
\frac{dC}{dt}= &k_{C} p_{C} A_1 \frac{C}{N_1} + (1-k_{C} p_{C}) k_{E} p_{E} A_1 \frac{E}{N_2} - \phi_{B} C \frac{B}{N_1} - (1-\phi_{B}) \phi_{D} C \frac{D}{N_2} + \phi_{C} B \frac{C}{N_1} +\\
& (1-\phi_{C}) \phi_{E} B \frac{E}{N_2} - \mu_{C} C - \gamma_{C} C \\
%
\frac{dA_2}{dt}=&\mu_2 N_2 - k_{D} p_{D} A_2 \frac{D}{N_2} - (1-k_{D} p_{D}) k_{B} p_{B} A_2 \frac{B}{N_1} - k_{E} p_{E} A_2 \frac{E}{N_2} - (1-k_{E} p_{E}) k_{C} p_{C} A_2 \frac{C}{N_1} -\\
& \mu_{A_2} A_2 + \gamma_{D} D + \gamma_{E} E \\
%
\frac{dD}{dt}= &k_{D} p_{D} A_2 \frac{D}{N_2} + (1-k_{D} p_{D}) k_{B} p_{B} A_2 \frac{B}{N_1} - \phi_{E} D \frac{E}{N_2} - (1-\phi_{E}) \phi_{C} D \frac{C}{N_1} + \phi_{D} E \frac{D}{N_2} +\\
& (1-\phi_{D}) \phi_{B} E \frac{B}{N_1} - \mu_{D} D - \gamma_{D} D \\
%
\frac{dE}{dt}= &k_{E} p_{E} A_2 \frac{E}{N_2} + (1-k_{E} p_{E}) k_{C} p_{C} A_2 \frac{C}{N_1} - \phi_{D} E \frac{D}{N_2} - (1-\phi_{D}) \phi_{B} E \frac{B}{N_1} + \phi_{E} D \frac{E}{N_2} +\\
& (1-\phi_{E}) \phi_{C} D \frac{C}{N_1} - \mu_{E} E - \gamma_{E} E 
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]